# Does 「ビールをたくさん飲まないほうがいい」sound right?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to say "you shouldn't drink a lot of (much) beer" and i'm wondering if I can use たくさん in this way to mean "a lot" (i.e. much).

Answer (score 3):

> 「ビール**を**たくさん飲{の}まないほうがいい。」

indeed sounds O.K.　「たくさん」 can be replaced by 「大量{たいりょう}に」.

It would, however, sound more natural if you said:

> 「ビール**は**たくさん飲まないほうがいい。」

It was great that you placed 「たくさん」 right before the verb.  What I often see/hear Japanese-learners do is to place it before the noun as in 「たくさんのビールを飲む」, which is just a direct translation from another language rather than very natural-sounding Japanese.

Comment: In fact, たくさんのビール sounds to me more like "too many beer**s**", with the imagery of many empty bottles/mugs.  This *could* be interchangeable depending on the context, but if you're speaking uncountably about "beer" in general (i.e., not a specific number of units), then it wouldn't be.